# Understanding long Japanese noun sentences 登校拒否になって家に引きこもったクラスメートを心配して励ましているうちに

Tags: meaning, parsing

> というのは、中学の時、登校拒否になって家に引きこもったクラスメートを心配して励ましているうちに、私は自身がストレスで髪が抜けたり食欲がなくなったりした経験があるからです。それで母は、私が他の人の悩みを聞いて、一緒に悩んでしまうのが、心配でたまらないというのです

For example I want to cut this sentence 登校拒否になって家に引きこもったクラスメートを心配して励ましているうちに  like this:

> 登校拒否になって家に引きこもっ**た**///クラスメートを心配して励ましているうちに

**My attempt to translate:** Staying in house and refused to go to school // while being encouraged and worried by friends

**My interpretation:**

というのは-から (because)

First I thought the subject was クラスメート but then I see 私は自身がストレス

At first I thought the subject was クラスメート, and 登校拒否になって家に引きこもった modified クラスメート, then I see を心配して励ましているうちに. This part made me think the one being encouraged was my classmate (登校拒否になって家に引きこもったクラスメートを心配して励ましているうちに)

But then the latter part 私は自身が。。 ->so the subject is me and I was supposed to be the one being encouraged by my friend.

**My question:**

Actually who is being encouraged? And who is encouraging?

How should I cut Japanese long sentence like this and how to determine who is the subject and who is object or modifier? Can you explain the structure also?

Comment: It's more about formatting than content itself, but could you please make it clearer what part represents citation, your translation attempt, your interpretation, or your question?

Comment: You were on the right track until you hit the latter part. What is it about 私は自身が that could reverse your initial judgement (that the one who is being encouraged is the classmate )? It begins the main clause, what came before being the dependent clause. Different clauses, different sets of subject and predicate (or topic and comment); Each communicates a different (though related) idea .  私は自身が, conveying the topic (私) and the subject (自身) of the latter (main) clause , bears no direct syntactic connection with the predicate of the previous clause, 心配して励ましている.

Comment: Instead, look for its comment/predicate within its own clause, and you'll find ストレスで髪が抜けたり食欲がなくなったりした経験がある.

Comment: Thankyou so much!!!! At that time i was confused because there are two subject there 私 and classmate, and also because the main subject is 私 so i thought that the prior part should explain 私 and just my feeling that classmate are the one who encourage me, but now i understood that verb before noun modify the noun and really important to find the main subject

Comment: @DevinaMuljono You are welcome. Your question is pretty good. Cutting sentence is the most important subject to understanding Japanese:)

Comment: "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar" has a pretty good appendix on breaking down and understanding sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

登校拒否になって家に引きこもったクラスメートを心配して励ましているうちに means " As I worried about and encouraged my classmate who was staying in house and refused to go to school." So my classmate is the one who was encouraged and I am the one who encouraged my classmate.

I can only say for your last question that you just have to read many Japanese sentences.

Comment: The one with particle は attach is always subejct(?).            登校拒否になって家に引きこもったクラスメートを->become object  and 心配して励ましているうちに->私 right?

Comment: The sentence [登校拒否になって家に引きこもった] in this situation is used as a adj. for クラスメート

Comment: Yes, right. は is mainly used as a topic maker, contrast and emphasis. There are many explanations about the difference between は and が. http://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E3%81%AF%E3%80%80%E3%81%8C  Particle は don't always attach after subject like 私は、英語は勉強しています, This second は attach after object.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the subject will be omitted or moved to the rear part in a sentence. In your question, it should be **私は**中学の時、登校拒否になって....

The subject is not omitted, but it shared the rear one[うちに、**私は**自身がストレスで]

というのは、I think it's similar to [The thing is...or The story is...]

When you see a **Verb. before a noun** in the sentence, you should take the whole part before it as a adjective.

So in this article the **main sentence** is 私は自身がストレスで髪が抜けたり食欲がなくなったりした経験があるからです. All the part before is just to modify うちに、 and it is to show you when(because there is a Verb. before **うち**に).

It's because there is a からです。so you will think というのは means because.

So the point to understand long Japanese sentence is to :

**1.Find all the noun in the sentence.**

**2.Find all the part to modify the noun find in 1.**

Answer (score -1):

というのは、中学の時、登校拒否になって家に引きこもったクラスメートを心配して励ましているうちに、私は自身がストレスで髪が抜けたり食欲がなくなったりした経験があるからです。それで母は、私が他の人の悩みを聞いて、一緒に悩んでしまうのが、心配でたまらないというのです。

What I mean is, when I was in junior high school, I was anxious about encouraging my classmate who was refused to attend school and grounded at home. I had personally experienced falling hair and loss of appetite due to stress. So, my mother told me, when I hear other’s troubles, it makes me worried too and It can’t be helped.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you helped work through the logic.  The question wasn't just asking for a translation, but also for a deeper understanding of how the Japanese language works.  Could you edit your question to address some of the other questions being asked in addition to understanding the  text?